# How to create a soft body in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

So.

After many years of iOS development I said it's time to try to do a little game for myself. Now I chose to do it using Apple's SceneKit since it looks like it provides everything I need.

My problem is that I've stumbled upon a huge problem (for me) and searching on Google doesn't yeld any results.

Any idea how do I go about having an object (a sphere for that matter) that deforms itself, say, because of a gravitational force. So basically it should squash on impact with the ground.

Or, how do I go about deforming it when it collides with other spheres, like a soft beach ball would?

Any starting point along those lines would be helpful.

I can post my code here, but I'm afraid it has nothing to do with my problem since I really don't know where to start.

Thanks!

**Update**

After doing a bit more reading I think that what I want could be doable with Vertex Shaders. Is that a right path to follow?

Comment: My advice: run as far away from scenekit as you can.

Comment: Do you have explicit reason for that? What do you recommend as an alternative?

Comment: Approximately 100 people in the world use SceneKit. You can check SO forums and you will see 6 questions in the last 3 days. It is currently a death technology. Even Apple didn't provide A programming guide. Meaning what? Meaning that you are alone! Nobody will answer your questions properly here, you will spend days trying to figure out why exactly sth doesn't work and at the end of the week you will have no idea what to do. I recently contacted Apple for SceneKit support and even the guy that was entitled to me didn't actually know what to do.

Comment: you may think that you have a headstart because you already know iOS frameworks and Swift or objc. Trust me, it is easier to learn a new language than trying to debug a death technology. I cannot say what you should use. I am trying libGDX which has awesome community support and a good reputation on the internet and it is free. The other option i was thinking about is unity.

Comment: @krompir2: I think you mean "dead technology"? A "death technology" sounds like something that kills people. Anyhow, SceneKit is neither. Apple continues to add features with each annual OS release, and despite the lack of an official guide, the reference documents are very thorough.

Comment: @krompir2 is right, though, that you're looking at a tough problem. SceneKit is a high level technology that manages a lot of lower level things for you — if you want to do different lower level things, SceneKit can't help much. It does provide some hooks so that you can do your own lower level stuff in the same context, but that sometimes involves working around SceneKit subsystems instead of with them. For example, you can do your own soft-body physics (with a third party library) and render results with OpenGL or Metal, but they won't interact with `SCNPhysics` stuff.

Comment: "death technology", sometimes I make myself laugh :D

Answer (score 1):

For complicated animations, you'll generally be better off using a 3D modeling tool like Blender, Maya, or Cheetah3D to build the body and construct the animation. Those tools let you think at a higher level of abstraction. Then you can export that model to Collada (DAE) format and then import it into SceneKit.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Basic_Animation/Bounce has a tutorial on building a deforming, bouncing ball using Blender.

Comment: That is sweet indeed. But my bouncing ball was just an example. What I really want to accomplish is have a couple of balls on a plane that can move freely and every time they collide I want them to kind of squish each other. I think that's hard to do with pre designed animations :-s

Comment: Yeah, that sounds hard! So perhaps you don't construct the animation frame by frame, but instead use the 3D tool to build a flexible skeleton, with a skin, that can deform under SceneKit physics. My strong hunch, though, is that using a 3D tool to build this will be much faster and easier than implementing all of the geometry and normal computation yourself. Note, btw, that the 2013 and 2014 WWDC SceneKit talks were written in SceneKit (not in Keynote), so each slide is its own sample code for a particular feature. Video, transcript, and source code are all available.

Answer (score 0):

SceneKit only does physics using rigid bodies. If you want something to deform, you would have to do it yourself.

It is probably because SceneKit has no way of knowing how an object should be deformed. Should it just compress, should it compress in one direction and expand in all others to preserve it's volume, should only part of the model compress and the rest stay rigid (like the tires on a car).

What you could try is wait for a collision to occur and do the following

```
calculate and store the velocity after the bounce
disable collision checking on the object
run an animation for the "squash"
enable collision checking on the object
apply the calculated velocity
```

It will be entirely up to you how real or cartoony you want to make the bounce look.